Is it possible to have a Static route segment in under a Dynamic Segments in NextJs 14
I have Dynamic route segment. I need to have a static segment for each route created for the dynamic routes. here is my expected file structure.
├── app/
│   └── blog/
│       └── [tag]/
│           ├── page.jsx
│           └── feed/
│               └── route.jsx

Is that possible to achive?
I've done this by /blog/[tag]/[feed]. made both segment dynamic. but I think that's unnecessary.
Here is my current structure
    ├── app/
    │   └── blog/
    │       └── [tag]/
    │           ├── page.jsx
    │           └── [feed]/
    │               └── route.jsx

and my route.jsx
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const tags = await getTags();
  const urls = tags.map((tag) => {
    const tagSlug = tag?.slug;
    return { tagName: tagSlug, feed: "feed" };
  });
  
  return urls;
}

export async function GET(request, { params }) {
   //get the path from the request
  const { tagName, feed } = params;
   if (feed !== "feed") {
     // redirect to the tag page
     return Response.redirect(`/tag/${tagName}`, 301);
   }

....

return new Response(feedData.xml({ indent: true }), {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  });
}

If this is not the only way then in /[tag]/feed how could I get the 'tag' name for the current tag. Like if the route is example.com/blog/mapping/feed/ then I need the tag slug 'mapping' to fetch the feed for mapping tag.
n/b: Using output: "export"
